# Selectize + Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, selectize.js

I wanted to add to my webpage a simple tagging option, using Selectize for Django. I first created a ModelForm as follows:

```
class Tag_forms(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = case
        fields = ['tags']   
        widgets = {
        'tags': tag_widget.TagSelectize(attrs={
                        'placeholder': '',
                            }),
        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Tag_forms, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['tags'].widget.attrs.update({})
```

After pasting the above ModelForm into HTML doc via Django tagging + attachment of JS and CSS for Selectize, I get a working tag window - so far so good.

However, the problems start when I try to implement some Bootstrap form formatting into the mix. The HTML structure this Django implementation builds looks like so:

[image]

Which produces view like this one:

[image]

However, when I try and add form-control class to the "selectize-control"  to format everything in it nicely and align it with Bootstrap goodness, I get the following:

[image]

Its functionality is intact, but "selectize-control" and "selectize-input" divs get misaligned. I can apply form-control to the inner one, but then I lose the ability to see effects of adding "is-valid / is-invalid" classes to any of these divs - green/red frame is just not visible.

Not only that, I cannot really add id or any real attribute to the 2nd inpu box in that code as well - when I work these wanted parameters into the ModelForm code, they appear on the outer input box, which does not even get displayed.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I used [selectize.bootstrap4.css](https://github.com/const-se/selectize-bootstrap4-theme) instead of the default css. More info [here](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/905#issuecomment-420330686)

Answer (score -1):

Remove class form-control from select input